# Python Dictionay sort

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
>>> x = {'a':2, 'c': 1, 'b':3}
```

There is no method available in dictionary to sort the dictionary by value. I sorted it using

```
>>> sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> sorted_x
[('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

but now when I convert to `sorted_x` to dictionary again by using loop. like

```
>>> new_dict = {}
>>> for i in sorted_x:
    new_dict[i[0]] = i[1]
>>> new_dict
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}
```

The `new_dict` again remains unsorted. Why the python dictionary cannot be sorted by key? can anyone shed light on it.

Comment: @LevLevitsky  I had used the same question to resolve my issue, I am asking about why dictionary are always unsorted, if I add value in sorted manner. so its not duplicate one.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries in python are hash maps. The keys are hashed in order to keep a fast access to the elements.

This means that internally the elements must be ordered depending on the hash they generate, not depending on the order you want to give.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are unsorted. They're just mappings between keys and values.

If you want a sorted dictionary, use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_x)
>>> d
    OrderedDict([('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)])
>>> d['c']
    1
```

Comment: yes! its possible to sort dictionary using this way, but I am asking about why dictionary are always unsorted, if I add value in sorted manner.

Comment: because are hash maps. This guarantees a fast lookup ( O(1) ). They are just mapping between keys and values, as blender already said. The implementation does not preserve the order, so it does not matter in which way you add values to them